# How can I override the AttributeError to make my script continue

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, attributeerror, continue

I'm trying to override the AttributeError message, so that it does not give me the error message and just continues with the script. The script finds and prints the office_manager name, but on some occasions there is no manager listed, as such I need it to just ignore those occasions. Can anyone help?

```py
for office_manager in soup.find(text="Office_Manager").findPrevious('h4'):
    try:
        print(office_manager)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
    finally:
        print("none")
```

Comment: `pass` instead of `continue`

Comment: beside the straight forward pass approach one can avoid the try,except and finally by sorting out the empty one using list comprehensions: `for office_manager in [x.findPrevious('h4') for x in soup.find(text="Office_Manager") if x not None]` . Actually is not there a find_all function as well? So `for x in soup.find_all(text="Office_Manager"): print(x.findPrevious('h4'))` should be an option as well

Comment: where do you see office_manager in https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/00930291/officers  ? There is not even an h4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1. you can use `:contains, :has and :not`. The following prints the directors names (if there are no directors you will get an empty list)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/00930291/officers')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
names = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('[class^=appointment]:not(.appointments-list):has([id^="officer-role-"]:contains(Director)) h2')]
print(names)
```

Comment: That's bloody brilliant (can you tell I'm new to this)! Thanks a million :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the error came from .find, then it should be the one to be on the try catch, or even better it should be like this.

```py
try:
    office_manager = soup.find(text="Office_Manager").findPrevious('h4')
except AttributeError as err:
    print(err) # or print("none")
    pass # return or continue
else:
   for title in office_manager:
       print(title)
```

Answer (score -1):

I thought someone less lazy than me would convert my comment to an answer, but as not, here you go:

```
for office_manager in soup.find(text="Office_Manager").findPrevious('h4'):
    try:
        print(office_manager)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    finally:
        print("none")
```

Using `pass` will skip the entry instead.

Comment: Thanks Nordle. I've tried it, but it still comes up with the error:
for office_manager in soup.find(text="Office Manager").findPrevious('h4'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findPrevious'